# firestore data model using multiple sub collections

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a current structure in my firestore.

Data model:

```
- users (collection)
    - 9d5UCo4RtyTosiFAIvnPK4zFCUk1 ( each user is a separate document )
        - trips ( collection )
            - New York (Document)
               - fields: date, description, photos:[url1, url2, ....] ( fields in the New York document), status:public
            - Los Angeles
               ....
```

Now I want to add notes, likes and metadata for each photo in the New York, LA, etc photos array.
I have a few ideas but not sure which is scalable and works well for what I want to do with notes, likes and metadata.

The notes don't have to load at the same time the photos do. The user would click to open notes which could be a new query to DB. But each photo does need to know how many notes are associated with each photo when photos are been displayed.

Solution 1:

photos array would be an object instead.

```
const photos = {
  isdffd: {
    url: "path",
    likes: 100,
    metadata: {
       ... 
    },
  },
  xxydfsd: {
    url: `path`,
    likes: 10,
    metadata: {
        ...
    }
  },
};
```

Then I have a collection of notes back up where trips is and use the photo id as the id for the note. but that limits me to 1 note per photo which I want to be able to add multiple notes.

I also want to be able to build a search page which would search through all notes throughout all trips and display them grouped by trip in the results.

What would be a good approach for this kind of setup with what I have right now which is using sub-collections for most of my structure so far.

Solution 2:

add another sub-collection inside each trip document called photos
each photo would be its own document with likes, metadata and notes. But then notes needs to be a sub-collection of each photo document. This would make it hard to search all trips and all notes for each photo.

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo as you can see from my post the query so far would be  users > userId > trips > trip document > fields: date, description, photos: []. Query: collection("users")
    .doc(userId as string)
    .collection("trips")
    .get();

Comment: The above query is fine for now but I want to add multiple notes to each photo in the array of trip document. This is where the sub-sollections could get deep and not sure if thats a good idea to add more sub-collections or to add a notes sub-collection higher up like my first preposed solution. Maybe read through the post again and focus on the notes part. Thanks for your feedback.  One other important note is I want to be able to easily search over all notes which would be hard to do with deep nested sub collections from what I'm reading in the docs.

Comment: So to understand better, the problem is more related to the fact that you don't know if it's better to nest some subcollections rather than adding a top-level collection?

Comment: Yes thats one part of the question. The other parts are based on the answer to that question. For example best way to handle a search throughout all notes if they are sub collections of other nested collections as I've shown in both the post and my answer above the setup I currently have.

Comment: @Me-me: You should post both of your solutions as formal answers to keep the post alive and help future users that have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way your original function has been structured:

```
- users (collection)
    - 9d5UCo4RtyTosiFAIvnPK4zFCUk1 ( each user is a separate document )
        - trips ( collection )
            - New York (Document)
               - fields: date, description, photos:[url1, url2, ....] ( fields in the New York document), status:public
            - Los Angeles
               ....
```

If you implement the first solution, you will limit your code if in the future you want to add another field to the photos object, or as you add [additional photos to the object](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

Adding a photos sub-collection inside your trips is your best option, this way your collection can grow and avoid the limitation of the first solution (having to make any change manually). If your notes are only text, then you can keep them inside each photo document as an array, avoiding another subcollection. Keeping the photos as a sub-collection and keeping the URL, likes, metadata and notes (if they are only text) inside each photo created should not add much difficulty when querying.